# Need help converting AJAX code to jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can someone please help me convert the code below to jQuery?

```
var xmlhttp;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                // Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                // Code for IE5, IE6
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.my.com", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("MyHeader", "hello");
            xmlhttp.send();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
                {
                    document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }   
            }
         }
```

Comment: What have you tried and what problems did you run into? Noone* is going to want to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example...

```
$.ajax({
  "type": "get", // optional
  "url": "http://www.my.com",
  "headers": { "MyHeader": "hello" },
  "success": function (data) {
    document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = data;
  }
});
```

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more options.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The code works with Firefox and Chrome but not with IE 8. Any idea why?

Comment: @Joly What is not working exactly? Do you get an error? You can try Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to see what goes over the wire. Any clues would be useful. jQuery version?

Comment: jQuery version: 1.8.0. I just noticed something strange: If I use my code above then it works with IE8 and doesn't work with FF 14.0 and Chrome 21.0 due to same origin policy ("is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error). If I use your code then it doesn't work in IE or FF (no error is given) and not in Chrome where again I'm getting the same error as with my code: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://.... Origin http://... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: OK fixed by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * on the other side

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET', // get by default anyway
  url: 'http://www.my.com',
  contentType: 'your/header',
  success: function(data){
    $('#responseText').html(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Look at the API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Should be something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.my.com',
  headers: {
     "key": "value"
  },
  onSuccess: function(data){
     $('#responseText').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I'm not an AJAX expert, but it looks like you're trying to make a GET request and read a response.
If so - you need to do following:

```
$.get('http://www.my.com/page.php?variable1=value1', function(data){
   $('#responseText').html(data);
})
```

Something like that.