# Converting xmlhttp javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My problem is that my code is really long and complicated, because it's normal xmlhttp and I want to switch it over to jQuery. I'm pretty sure there's shorthand functions for it? This is my current code:

```
function getContent() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

            replace_page = xmlhttp.responseText;
            doc.getElementById("content").innerHTML = replace_page;

            $("#content").children().hide();
            $("#content").children().fadeIn("slow");

            //do some other stuff
        }
        navigating = false;
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET",site_location+"/pages/"+page+".php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077991/need-help-converting-ajax-code-to-jquery), and this works perfectly, but I'm also going to have to use this for forms...

Is there a simple way I can change it? I know it'll probably involve the serialising function, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/);

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: site_location+"/pages/"+page+".php",
}).done(function(html){
    $('#content').html(html).children().hide().fadeIn("slow");
})
```

or better using [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) since the objective is to load a html content to a target element

```
$('#content').load(site_location+"/pages/"+page+".php", function(){
    $(this).children().hide().fadeIn("slow");
})
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have in the example link. How would I make it work for forms tho?

Comment: Ooh! Load is better! I would have made that mistake. By doing the ajax, I could have the option of doing form content too, tho, right?

Comment: @Aarilight sorry, what do you mean by `I could have the option of doing form content too, tho, right?`

Comment: Like, how do I use this for submitting a form and getting the response?

Comment: @Aarilight like `$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'target-url',
    data: $('form').serialize()
}).done(function (data) {
    //do something with data
})`

Comment: What does the lambda function receive in .done()? Is it the responseHTML? ("data")

Comment: it depends on what the the data type... it can be a html, json, text, xml etc... you may have to read about jQuery ajax and how it can be used

Comment: All right! Thank you so much for your help. I promise I'm done now. =)